# How to constrain 2 dictionaries where one is driver and one driven object per key

Tags: python, maya, mel

I am learning Maya Python as part of the art school program but since the teacher is not very competence so I am looking for help with this homework.

So the task is basically:
Create 2 dictionaries and constrains the values of one key to the other. But I should see one driver and one driven object per key

```py
def ConstraintDict():

category = {
    "brand",
    "model",
    "year"
}


car = {
    "Mazada",
    "626",
    "1994"
}
```

brand should be driven by Mazda

model should be driven by 626

year driven by 1994

I have been trying to search for a solution and haven't found a proper answer yet.

Please help me out with this

Comment: Any reason you made `category` and `car` as sets? construct them as lists and do `dict(zip(category, car))`

Comment: For me you are trying to solve something that should be using class. I would have created a Human class and a Vehicle class where I would have a method for assigning Human